# Show $\phi^{-1}(K)=\{g\in G\mid \phi(g)\in K\}$ forms a subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G,H$ be groups, $\phi:G\rightarrow H$ be a homomorphism, and $K\leq H$. Show that the pre-image of $K$, which is the set $\phi^{-1}(K)=\{g\in G\mid \phi(g)\in K\}$, forms a subgroup of $G$.

---

Since $G,H$ are groups and $K\leq H$, $e\in G$ such that $\phi(e)=e'\in K$, hence $\phi^{-1}(K) \neq \emptyset$. Let $a,b\in \phi^{-1}(K)$, then $\phi(a),\phi(b)\in K$  which are also in $H$. Then apply the one step subgroup test, $\phi(a-b)=\phi(a)+\phi(-b)=\phi(a)-\phi(b)\in K$, thus $\phi^{-1}(K)$ is a subgroup of $G$.

---

Does the proof valid? And I want to make sure that I read $\phi^{-1}$ correct: there exist an element $g$ in $G$ such that $\phi(g)$ in $K$, and if I have element $k$ in $K$ then $\phi^{-1}(k)=g$ for some $g$ in $G$.

Comment: It looks like you're mixing notations. We usually don't use additive notation, or 0 for identity, unless the groups are abelian.

Comment: I believe the OP means that $\phi^{-1}(K)$ is nonempty.

Comment: I have to agree with Alex. When you've written the binary operations in additive notation, it implies the groups are abelian. This is the convention that I've seen in textbooks, but i'm sure OP didn't intend it to be so.

Comment: use \mid for $\mid$ in $\{\cdot \mid \cdot \}$. Edited.

Comment: Your proof seems good. Be careful not to confuse the preimage and inverses. You can definitely find that explanation in wiki and there's a nice and brief explanation on it.